# Selenium IDE script not working in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I created some Selenium IDE scripts, then exported the scripts in Java/Junit4 webdriver backed and just simple webdriver classes . When i run these classes the only thing that the testcase does is open the right URL. After that the testcase which is a login test case it cannot find userName field at all. I tried by name or by id both does work at all. I even tried to add some methods to make a wait to wait for the page to load (which actually loads without issue); i was expecting by name or by id parts to work at least the last try block uses a method i found on the net to keep on looking for the userName field but i am surfe will not be needed if i solve the frist two try blocks. i tried some resources on line which are there on the stackoverflow or other forums but its kinda very confusing that a simple script from IDE wont work this easily.

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

package com.mycomp.selenium.uatseleniumsuite.test;

/**
*
* @author sar
*/


import com.mycomp.selenium.uatseleniumsuite.login.PaymentsTabWithCssTest;
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class TestloginSampleTest {

private String baseUrl;
private static WebDriver driver;
private ScreenshotHelper screenshotHelper;
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestloginSampleTest.class.getName());


@Before
public void openBrowser() {
baseUrl = "https://255.255.255.255:11115/myCompWebApp/login.go?siteLanguage=en&checked=true";
System.out.print("BASE URL IS  : "+baseUrl);
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get(baseUrl);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
screenshotHelper = new ScreenshotHelper();
}

@After
public void saveScreenshotAndCloseBrowser() throws IOException {
screenshotHelper.saveScreenshot("screenshot.png");
driver.quit();
}

@Test
public void UATLogin() throws IOException {
System.out.print("title : "+driver.getTitle());
assertEquals("The page title should equal mycomp at the start of the test.", "myCompOnline - Corporate", driver.getTitle());
try{
WebElement fuzoolPageCloseField = driver.findElement(By.id("splash-32856-close-button"));
System.out.print("fuzoolPageCloseField  : Found ");
fuzoolPageCloseField.click();
System.out.print("fuzoolPageCloseField  : Clicked ");
WebElement userNameField = driver.findElement(By.id("userName"));
System.out.print("userNameField  : Found ");
userNameField.sendKeys("myusername");
}catch( NoSuchElementException nse){
logger.error("EXCEPTION  by id: NoSuchElementException ");
System.out.print("EXCEPTION  by id: NoSuchElementException ");
nse.printStackTrace();
}catch(StaleElementReferenceException ser){
logger.error("EXCEPTION  : StaleElementReferenceException ");
System.out.print("EXCEPTION  : StaleElementReferenceException ");
ser.printStackTrace();

}


try{
WebElement userNameField = driver.findElement(By.name("userName"));
userNameField.sendKeys("myusername");
}catch( NoSuchElementException nse){
logger.error("EXCEPTION  By name : NoSuchElementException ");
System.out.print("EXCEPTION  BY name : NoSuchElementException ");
nse.printStackTrace();
}catch(StaleElementReferenceException ser){
logger.error("EXCEPTION  : StaleElementReferenceException ");
System.out.print("EXCEPTION  : StaleElementReferenceException ");
ser.printStackTrace();

}

try{
String myWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.switchTo().window(myWindowHandle);
WebDriverWait wait = (WebDriverWait)new WebDriverWait(driver,10)
.ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);
assertTrue("The page title should start with the search string after the search.",
(wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() { //last exception comes here for timeout
@Override 
public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
WebElement userNameField = driver.findElement(By.name("userName"));
userNameField.sendKeys("myusername");
return true;
}
})
));
}catch( NoSuchElementException nse){
logger.error("EXCEPTION after driver getwindowhandle : NoSuchElementException ");
System.out.print("EXCEPTION  : NoSuchElementException ");
nse.printStackTrace();
}catch(StaleElementReferenceException ser){
logger.error("EXCEPTION  : StaleElementReferenceException ");
System.out.print("EXCEPTION  : StaleElementReferenceException ");
ser.printStackTrace();

}



}

private class ScreenshotHelper {

public void saveScreenshot(String screenshotFileName) throws IOException {
File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File(screenshotFileName));
}
}

public void waitForElementPresent(final By by, int timeout){ 
WebDriverWait wait = (WebDriverWait)new WebDriverWait(driver,timeout)
.ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class); 
wait.until(new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition<Boolean>(){ 
@Override 
public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) { 
WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(by); 
return element != null && element.isDisplayed(); 
} 
}); 
}
public static WebElement getElementByLocator( final By locator ) {
//  LOGGER.info( "Get element by locator: " + locator.toString() );  
final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>( driver )
.withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.ignoring( StaleElementReferenceException.class ) ;
int tries = 0;
boolean found = false;
WebElement we = null;
while ( (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) < 91000 ) {
//   LOGGER.info( "Searching for element. Try number " + (tries++) ); 
try {
we = wait.until( ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated( locator ) );
found = true;
break;
} catch ( StaleElementReferenceException e ) {      
//    LOGGER.info( "Stale element: \n" + e.getMessage() + "\n");
}
}
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
if ( found ) {
//   LOGGER.info("Found element after waiting for " + totalTime + " milliseconds." );
} else {
//   LOGGER.info( "Failed to find element after " + totalTime + " milliseconds." );
}
return we;
}


}
```

the "fuzoolPageCloseField" is a window which is loaded and clicked in the script it has a different name , but i saw that using chrome defveloper tools it had a differnt ID name so i used it in webdriver as "splash -something" The original name works in IDE some how.

the stack trace is as below:

Stack trace comes with exception of NoSuchElementException in 10 seconds interval due to the driver timeout, the last exception comes at `line 110(wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {`

```
cd C:\NetBeansProject\Selenium\testseleniumsuite; JAVA_HOME=D:\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_45 M2_HOME=D:\\APIs\\Maven\\Binary\\apache-maven-3.0.4 cmd /c "\"\"D:\\APIs\\Maven\\Binary\\apache-maven-3.0.4\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dtest=com.mycomp.selenium.testseleniumsuite.test.TestloginSampleTest -DnetbeansProjectMappings= -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"D:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 7.4\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" surefire:test\"\""
Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building testseleniumsuite 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-cli) @ testseleniumsuite ---
Surefire report directory: C:\NetBeansProject\Selenium\testseleniumsuite\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.mycomp.selenium.testseleniumsuite.test.TestloginSampleTest
BASE URL IS  : https://10.2.217.133:11115/myCompWebApp/login.go?siteLanguage=en&checked=trueStarting ChromeDriver (v2.8.241075) on port 21432
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
title : myCompOnline - CorporatefuzoolPageCloseField  : Found fuzoolPageCloseField  : Clicked    
  EXCEPTION  by id: NoSuchElementException org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=31.0.1650.63)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.8.241075,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 20.06 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time: '2013-12-16 13:18:38'
System info: host: 'P5510041A', ip: '10.32.245.103', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_45'
Session ID: 62d2adad3c6cd4479b26a0f1fdab838e
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\5510041\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir11832_12325}, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=31.0.1650.63, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:307)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:220)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:299)
    at com.mycomp.selenium.testseleniumsuite.test.TestloginSampleTest.UATLogin(TestloginSampleTest.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:69)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:48)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
EXCEPTION  BY name : NoSuchElementException org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=31.0.1650.63)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.8.241075,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 20.05 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time: '2013-12-16 13:18:38'
System info: host: 'P5510041A', ip: '10.32.245.103', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_45'
Session ID: 62d2adad3c6cd4479b26a0f1fdab838e
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\5510041\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir11832_12325}, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=31.0.1650.63, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:307)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByName(RemoteWebDriver.java:380)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName.findElement(By.java:305)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:299)
    at com.mycomp.selenium.testseleniumsuite.test.TestloginSampleTest.UATLogin(TestloginSampleTest.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:69)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:48)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 66.532 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Tests in error: 
  UATLogin(com.mycomp.selenium.testseleniumsuite.test.TestloginSampleTest): Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for com.mycomp.selenium.testseleniumsuite.test.TestloginSampleTest$1@1e78fc6

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1:07.488s
Finished at: Sun Dec 29 17:54:50 AST 2013
Final Memory: 4M/15M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-cli) on project testseleniumsuite: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\NetBeansProject\Selenium\testseleniumsuite\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
-> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Hope any one can help.

p.S I also ran the webdriver backed classes and they all failed at the same point as well (by webdriver backed i mean where you instantiate a selenium object and use that to do your tests but there even :   `selenium.click("id=splash-32856-close-button;");`  was not working, at least this si working in the driver object)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Look at the HTML in the web browser to find out why it is not working. I suspect you will find that the IDs are changing and that's why Selenium can't find them - because they're not there any more.

Comment: Thanks for reply Robin, I checked the chrome's developer tools console and the id and name is there as userName. the same script works in the selenium IDE. Could it be related to HTML5 OR my website having it's right click disabled. (we have disabled the right click for copy paste and view source options could that be an issue)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. The scripts from IDE work fine in IDE, when exporting them in java/Junit the statements were like

```
      driver.findElement(By.id("userName")).clear();
      driver.findElement(By.id("userName")).sendKeys("742817");
```

However, i debugged it manually and made sure i was getting into it. I think i had an iframe which is why the driver was not able to see the element.

So i searched for the iFrame and that worked.

```
  WebElement iframeWebelement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/form/...../tbody/tr/td/iframe"));
   System.out.println("iframeWebelement : Found ");

  driver.switchTo().frame(iframeWebelement);
   WebElement userNameField = driver.findElement(By.id("userName"));
    System.out.println("userName  : Found ");
        userNameField.sendKeys("myusername");
            System.out.println("userName  : entered data ");
```

this worked for me. I didnt knew that an iFrame would be something i needed to be switched to.

Hope this helps some one who is using iFrame.